# How to enable SSL excluding specific directories AND excluding subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, subdomain

**I want:**

1. Normalize "domain.com" to "www.domain.com"
2. Enable SSL, but:
3. Exclude SSL from /PHP/*
4. Exclude SSL from specific page "noSSL.htm"

**This is what I have:**

```
#enable SSL excluding /PHP directory
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule !^php/.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#Enable SSL and add "www." if missing
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ https%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**Questions/Issues:**

- Issue: Subdomains gets SSL
- How to exclude a specific file from SSL?
- Do I need to repeat "RewriteEngine On"?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: you have already excluded /php/ directory so you could add that file beside it like this RewriteRule !^(php/.*|.*file\.php)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Comment: Would this exclude a .php file? And how to disable SSL from subdomains, please?

Comment: Yes it will exclude the spacificfile.php if you do it like this , for sub doamins you could add this before rules RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$  [NC] then put the rest that start with RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443

Comment: Sorry, but I am new to it. Could you post the entire code block?

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment , The rules should look like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule !^(php/.*|.*noSSL\.htm)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^  http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

So `noSSL.htm` will be excluded .

**Note:**  clear browser cache then test.

Comment: Still one problem: [http://www.example.com](http://www.example.com) does not get SSL